# Remap key combos to symbol characters

Tags: keyboard

For my home workstation I use a Moonlander which lets you add different layer-shifting to any key, and define each of the layers with whatever character desired.

For example, I'd have a symbols layer triggered by holding the "f" key.  From there, The "j" key would produce the "(" character, k would produce the ")" character, etc.

I realize that's the firmware on the keyboard doing the work there, but is there any way to get this type of custom behavior on the base laptop keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Ukelele](https://software.sil.org/ukelele/) remapping software.  It lets you remap all keys whenever option or option plus shift are held down, or when caps lock is turned on.  Also any key can be made a "dead key" (not held down) where the next key pressed produces whatever you want.

Another different remapping app is [Karabiner](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org).